# block simultaneously views for documents

Tags: document-library, document

We have to design a portal for all our engineer standards. One major point for this is to block simultaneously views of documents. So if the document is opened no one else should get the possibility to open the file. I had a look on Azure Information Protection but found nothing. 
Maybe somebody has a solution. 
Regards Michael

Comment: what kind of portal are you talking about? SharePoint? I think there is nothing that can stop multiple users from opening same document at once if they are using native MS apps or even Online apps like excel online, word online. through some light on (1) Technology behind portal (2) what kind of files (3) whether you have your own rendering engine to show the file content. Mainly, AIP does not have this capability as its related to labeling & protection.